# qml takes mouse click but not taking touch events

Tags: qt, touch, qml

I have a Qwidget inside of which, I have multiple children in the form of `QmlApplicationViewer` objects, each pointing to a different qml file.

Problem is, when I use mouse, all the qml files take events, but when I try to use the touch screen, only some of them does.

Can someone give a direction as to where the problem might be ? Will appreciate and sort of possible causes which might cause this issue.

Platform : Ubuntu 12.04 - Qt 4.8 - 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using the EG-Touch touch drivers for my platform, which are supposed to have some issues on 12.04(as per some forums). I reverted back to Ubuntu 11.04 and used the e-Galax touch drivers instead, and things are working fine now.

P.S. : If someone finds a working driver for 12.04 or any other work around, please update. I will accept a better answer. Closing this for now.

Answer (score 0):

There really is not enough information here to even begin to answer this question. The most obvious answer that comes to mind is some of your qml files are not correctly defining the TouchArea within the qml. If you want more help you need to post code.